# SQL that returns count of objects from sub-query used in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, oracle, count

How to extend this SQL query (Oracle) so that it also returned a count of all BROKEN_ITEMS?

```
select
    IT.ITEM_ID
from
    ITEMS IT
where
    IT.ITEM_ID not in (select BI.ITEM_ID
                         from BROKEN_ITEMS BI)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With subquery:

```
select
    IT.ITEM_ID,
    (select count(*) from BROKEN_ITEMS) BROKEN_ITEMS_COUNT
from
    ITEMS IT
where
    IT.ITEM_ID not in (select BI.ITEM_ID
                         from BROKEN_ITEMS BI)
```